# Jmeter regular exp extractor for xml

Tags: jmeter

I have the below message in the response and i would like to capture activity-name, old-val and new-val. Can someone please help me what is the best way to capture?

response message: I have multiple blocks as shown below, i have mentioned only one block here.

```
<tr>
                <td width="20%" class="activity-name">
                                    Programs Written/Modified
                                </td>
                <td width="40%" class="activity-old-val">
                                                </td>
                <td width="40%" class="activity-new-val">
                                                            <b>New:</b>
                                                                   buildrate.p
                                                                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), JMeter provides the following Post-Processors:

1. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor) which allows fetching data from HTML using [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)
2. [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) which allows fetching data from XHTML/XML and HTML using [XPath selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Demo:

[image]